# Comparing Objective-C Precompile Macros within Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, gnu, preprocessor

i have the following situation: Within my ios project file i set Precompile Macro
DEVELOPER=$(INSTALL_OWNER)

which is good for working in bigger teams and setting the UI different. The DEVELOPER constant now holds the install owner, which for example is peter. So with that, here comes my question:

Within the code, is it possible to ask or compare the DEVELOPER constant to a string or something else like "#if DEVELOPER==peter "?

Comment: See also: http://c-faq.com/cpp/ifstrcmp.html